Cartoon show about 5 heroes dressed like owls/birds
This show could be Japanese anime, but I am not sure. I saw this show in the 1980s and I vaguely remember 3 of the heroes. There is a standard hero (male, handsome). There is the typical girl (attractive) and there is the fat guy. I forgot how the other 2 heroes looked like.
But they all wear costumes that resemble owls or some sort of birds. 
The costume includes capes as well. I think there is a face shield (glass) maybe an extension of the beak bit of the owl face.. Not sure.
I forgot what they were fighting, or whether they had a ship or a mecha to fight with. 
I can only remember the end credits, there is a screenshot of the five guys running towards the audience.
I didn't speak English at the time, but I am sure I watched it in English. This means, if it was an original Japanese anime, it must've been officially dubbed into English.

You probably mean G-Force, a popular adaptation of Japanese anime series Science Ninja Team Gatchaman from 1986 with 5 superheroes dressed like birds:

Here's the intro:




Was going to post the same, +1.

Wow.. you never stop to amaze me.

The original show is called "Gatchaman". There was another adaptation for the western audience, "Battle of the Planets".

I remember it quite fondly. So I'm sorry about this, but I think I just have to. :)

If you watched the show in English in the 1980s, it may have been, as Vixen Populi noted, Battle of the Planets.  While about 90% of the footage would have mostly been from Science Ninja Team Gatchaman, it is not simply a translation of the original program; a US production company bought the right to distribute the film in the US with any changes they saw fit, and they made quite a few.  They added the somewhat goofy Seven-Zark-Seven and Center Neptune as a means of filling time, and also of patching over any story-continuity problems caused by other edits.
The original show had two different title songs; at least as distributed on DVD, each episode would use one in the opener and the other in the closer, though shows varied as to which song was used where. The BOTP shows all used the same title music (which was new to that program, and IMHO pretty cool) but the incidental music within the shows is derived from the original title music [something similar happened in Gilligan's Island, by the way: the show aired with a theme song by the Wellingtons, but the melody of the theme song from the unbroadcast pilot is quite recognizable within many episodes].
Somewhat curiously, even though the show's credits are rather long compared with other US cartoons of the day, the only reference to the Japanese crew responsible for 90% of the content was a single slide identifying Studio Toho Ltd.
